# Swapping between youtube embeds with image hyperlink clicks?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, embed

Here's what I'm trying to do. I have a bunch of thumbnails on a page and each one links to a page which has a youtube video embedded on it (so it's like a playlist). I was thinking it would be possible to simply swap out the current youtube embed rather than having it load an entirely new page.

The youtube embeds are iframes, so I'd need a way of, when clicking an image (I'm guessing javascript onclick might be the best solution) then have it change the current iframe to something else. I can do this linking to the pages which have the youtube embed, but I'd like to do it without needing to load a page - just grab some html and plug it in the iframe spot.

Any ideas?

Comment: Change `src` of iframe on click on thumbnail.

Answer (score 1):

**You don't need to use javascript to load something into an `iframe`.** You can add a `name` attribute to your `iframe` and then set the `target` of your link to that name. Something like this will work:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/zSgiXGELjbc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen name="youtube_iframe"></iframe>
<p><a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/DZGINaRUEkU" target="youtube_iframe">load another video</a></p>
```

See a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/q3Nas/